# NSDateFormatter style used in iOS Calendar

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I'm want to display the date such that it includes the day of the week, but no year, similar to what the iPhone Calendar app does. The problem I'm having is getting it to match the user's locale settings.

For reference, this is what the Calendar app displays for English and French:

[image: English date style]

[image: French date style]

Among the listed date styles for `NSDateFormatter` (Short, Medium, Long and Full) not one drops the year, and none looks quite like what the Calendar app is doing. In my case the app only supports English and French, and with two languages it may be ok to hard code the formatting, but there should be a better way!

EDIT:

The question referenced as duplicate does indeed provide the solution I was looking for. It's not entirely identical to Calendar style, but good enough.

Specifically, if I use the following code:

```
let dateForm = NSDateFormatter()
let format = NSDateFormatter.dateFormatFromTemplate("EEE MMM d", options: 0, locale: NSLocale.currentLocale())
dateForm.dateFormat = format
let dateString = dateForm.stringFromDate(myDate)
```

I get the following:

[image: English version]

[image: French version]

There is an extra comma in the English version, but it does not bother me.
Thanks for the pointer! Didn't realize that's how `dateFormatFromTemplate` worked.

Comment: Did you try dateFormatFromTemplate? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDateFormatter/dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:

Comment: When reviewing the duplicate, you'll need the use a format of `EEE MMM d`.

Comment: To be honest, this question has a slightly different angle to it than the supposed duplicate - it's not about removing the year, it's about whether there is a predefined date style that mimics the calendar's way of displaying a date ('by accident' without year). I'd leave the question open.

Comment: @TheEye No, they are the same. Both ask how to drop the year from the standard date formatter styles.

Comment: No, he asks if there is a better way, like a standard short format that does drop the year (and do some fancy stuff like starting with a small letter for the day in french), possibly named - instead of just dropping the year